# Evaluate the limit: $\lim_{x\to 0} x.\sin \left(\frac {1}{x} \right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate the limit: $\lim_{x\to 0} x.\sin \left(\dfrac {1}{x} \right)$

My Attempt:

We know,
$$-1\leq \sin \left(\dfrac {1}{x}\right) \leq 1$$
Multiplying each term by $x$
$$-x\leq x \sin \left(\dfrac {1}{x}\right) \leq x$$ for $x>0$

$$-x\geq x \sin \left(\dfrac {1}{x}\right) \geq x$$ for $x<0$

Comment: That's good, now what happens as $x$ gets closer to zero.

Comment: While your approach is good, you may also observe that a substitution $x=1/t$ leads you to an easier limit for which the squeeze theorem is not needed

Comment: @imranfat: I really don't get how $x=1/t$ helps here. Can you please elaborate further?

Comment: It is much simpler to apply the definition of limit here and show that the limit is $0$. Your approach needs to be completed via application of Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You get $\frac{sint}{t}$ with $t$ going to infinities. A bounded numerator divided by an unbounded denominator

Comment: @imranfat: the result you speak of is also dependent on squeeze or can be handled directly via limit definition. I find your result no more or less intuitive than "the product of a bounded function and a function tending to $0$ also tends to $0$". However one of the two forms may be more psychologically satisfying for different people. So it's more of a taste/preference thing.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I agree, that is why I used the word "also" in my comment. Just a slight different way of looking at the problem

Comment: @imranfat : got it! I perhaps misinterpreted your comment that substitution $x=1/t$ would lead to a much better solution. Anyway we are now on same page with this.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right approach, this is the canonical example of the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Take care to approach zero from both negative and positive sides and conclude that their limits are the same.